# How to get the Time difference of two input dates in C#

Tags: c#

Hi i'm trying to get the time difference in min but the given example uses a DateTime.now, though this works but I need to calculate time difference from two inputs, actually it's from a biometric data but for now i'll settle with a fix on this code

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now; //Current Date

//string startTime = "20/09/2023 4:40:02 PM"; // <-- this is supposedly the 1st input instead of DateTime.now
string dateString = "20/09/2023 5:22:02 PM";  //If Date is in String Format..

DateTime dateFromString = DateTime.Parse(dateString); //Parse the String to the DateTime
TimeSpan span = startTime.Subtract(dateFromString);
int Minutesdiff = span.Minutes;
int Hoursdiff = span.Hours;

richTextBox1.Text = (
                        "Start Time: "+startTime.ToString() +"\r\n"+
                        "End Time: " + dateString + "\r\n" +
                        "Time Difference (minutes): " + Minutesdiff.ToString() + "\r\n" +
                        "Time Difference (hours): " + Hoursdiff.ToString()
                    );
```

Comment: [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=net-7.0) didn't work for you? `Minutes` only gives you the minute part of the value. `TotalMinutes` gives you the value expressed as minutes.

Comment: Unrelated: Your implementation requires both timestamps to originate in the same TimeZone. If they can originate from anywhere on earth (and differently for start and end), you _have_ to take that into account.

Comment: A `DateTime` is a `DateTime`, regardless of where it comes from. `DateTime.Now` returns a `DateTime`. Why would that value be used any differently from one you get from the user or whatever? Why do you think the `Subtract` method should depend on the source of the values?

Comment: im not following you @jmcilhinney, i needed to be able to get the time difference so i can get if they are late or not, comparing their fingerprint time out on lunch break to DateTime.now doesn't make sense

Comment: So, what is the actual problem here? Obtaining the data to take the difference of or taking the difference? What stops you from doing `var startTimeFromString = DateTime.Parse(startTime);` ? // assuming the string version of `startTime`

Comment: it's probably because i don't know the code exist and i'm fairly new to c# but it's okay now, turned to chatGPT instead got a working code now thank you for your efforts guys and I'm sorry if i wasted your time

Comment: If I asked you to calculate the time difference between the current time and some other specified time, then I asked you to calculate the time difference between two specified times, would you do the two calculations differently? Of course you wouldn't, because that would be ridiculous. The current time is still a time. All you're doing is calculating the difference between two times, either way. That's my point. If you know how to subtract two `DateTime` values then it doesn't matter where those two values come from. The subtraction operation is still the same either way. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference between two DateTimes, just subtract them:

```
TimeSpan span = startTime - dateFromString;
```

If you want the absolute difference, use `span.Duration()`. If you want the total number of minutes, use `span.TotalMinutes`

To take the input from the user there is a [DateTimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) in winforms. I can only find a DatePicker in wpf, but some third party control likely exist for both date and time. You could also just add a textbox and parse the string, but there is a huge risk of the user using the wrong date time format.

Comment: I'm getting errors from your recommended code, would you be so kind to elaborate the code, the error is 
CS0019 Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'DateTime'

Comment: JonasH's Code assumes _your example_ in which both `startTime` and `dateFromString` are of type `DateTime`. Then the "-" operator is applicable. But it is pretty much equivalent to `startTime.Subtract(dateFromString)`.

Comment: i tried to change the datatypes from string to DateTime but i get a conversion error

Comment: @LouieJayOrellanaJayme This assumes both input values are `DateTime`. If you get an error when parsing you need to check the format of the input string.  This might depend on the culture. You might need to use [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-7.0) and supply a custom formatting string if you need to parse a specific format outside your control. And yes, as Fildor mentions using the subtraction operator or `.Subtract()` is equivalent.  But it sounds like your problem has more with inputting datetimes than computing the difference.